# To find the Generating function for the given case

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

$$a_{n} = \frac{4^{3n-5}}{3^{2n+4}}$$

I was just able to reach till $a_{n}$ = ($\frac{64}{9}$) $a_{n-1}$

Don't know how to proceed further

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: to find the generating function

Comment: Try the [formula for the sum of a geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula).

Comment: What about $a_{0}$?

Comment: Shit!!!! it's a GP :/ How could I miss it. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the formula for the sum of a geometric series:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{4^{3n-5}}{3^{2n+4}}x^n
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{81\cdot1024}\left(\frac{64}9x\right)^n\\
&=\frac1{9\cdot9216}\frac1{1-\frac{64}9x}\\
&=\frac1{9216}\frac1{9-64x}
\end{align}
$$